# How to add a identity column that is unique per grouping

Tags: sql-server-2005

Say I have 2 columns

```
Product     Product_Cat
-------     -----------
Cat         0
Dog         0
Potatoes    2
Carrots     2
Laundry     1
Bird        0
```

I want to add on a 3rd identity column but I want the numbering to be unique per Product_Cat
So the output would look like

```
Product     Product_Cat     Cat_Ident
-------     -----------     ---------
Cat         0               1
Dog         0               2
Potatoes    2               1
Carrots     2               2
Laundry     1               1
Bird        0               3
```

How do you do this?

---

This of course is not my real data but a simplification of what I want to do. in my live system I have 4585 different values of "Product_Cat" and they range from 1 to 2408 "Products" in the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Products
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Product nvarchar(8),
    Product_Cat int
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Products (Product, Product_Cat)
VALUES ('Cat', 0)
,('Dog', 0)
,('Potatoes', 2)
,('Carrots', 2)
,('Laundry', 1)
,('Bird', 0)
GO

ALTER TABLE #Products
    ADD Cat_Ident int
GO

UPDATE #Products
    SET Cat_Ident = rankVal
FROM #Products 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Cat ORDER BY ID ) AS rankVal
        FROM #Products ) rankings ON #Products.ID = rankings.ID

SELECT * FROM #Products

DROP TABLE #Products
```

Result is:

```
ID          Product  Product_Cat Cat_Ident
----------- -------- ----------- -----------
1           Cat      0           1
2           Dog      0           2
3           Potatoes 2           1
4           Carrots  2           2
5           Laundry  1           1
6           Bird     0           3

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need more info but it looks like you will need to use a trigger to form the value of cat_ident.

A simple `SELECT COUNT()+1 GROUP BY ProductCat` should help

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying to do, can you explane more?

Comment: @Scott Chamerlain - What I mean is in order to get the Cat_Ident number all you have to do is get a count of the product categories row. FOr instance look at your example, you have Cat 0 1. Meaning it was the first time product_cat came up so you assigned cat_ident 1. Then you have Dog 0 2, you saw that the product_cat already existed one time so all you did was add 1 to the count and assign it to Cat_Ident so you got the value 2. So it is a simple SQL Count by groupping: `SELECT Product_Cat, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable GROUP BY Product_Cat` That will give you a count of each group.

Comment: To get the next value you could do `SELECT @MyCount = (Count(*) + 1) FROM YourTable WHERE Product_Cat = 0` Now @MyCount has the next value to assign to Cat_Ident when you insert a row.

Comment: I don't care about inserting new rows. I want to update the existing rows. this is for a conversion from one database system to another and the destination needs unique identifiers based off the category. there will be no new rows added to this database.

Comment: Ok so you simply need to use an UPDATE statement / trigger rather then insert.  You may have to use an iterative approach as I cannot think of a SET based SQL Solution.  Maybe one of the other gurus can recommend a SET based UPDATE routine to handle this.  Iterative approach might be slow but would work.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO Products
           (Product
           ,Product_Cat
           ,Cat_Ident)
     VALUES
           ('Flower'
           ,1
           , (select ISNULL( (SELECT top (1) Cat_Ident +1  as x
               FROM Products
              where Product_Cat =1
                    order by  Cat_Ident desc),'1') ))
```